# Can someone explain to me the "I'll regroup at Red Lobster" joke in The Simpsons?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-simpsons

In the *Weekend at Burnsie's* episode (S13E16), Homer sees a scarecrow at his yard but, because it is dark, he thinks it is a man and runs away yelling:

> I'll regroup at Red Lobster

What does it mean? I've read in forums that this is one of the favorites Simpsons jokes for some fans, but I don't get it. Maybe it's a cultural reference I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Homer was not regrouping at a prearranged place, a safe point ***or*** a tactically strong point, but at a [sea food restaurant](http://www.redlobster.com/)!

Typical of Homer. The only thing that would be more typical of Homer is regrouping at either Moe's or a donut shop.

Comment: Also he's not exactly "regrouping" since it's just him, even more irony for ya.